# How to set the color of the dots except for the main diagonal in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This figure (fig_1) is a pairwise scatter plot on iris dataset. The diagonal plots the marginal histograms of the 4 features.

[image]

I am trying to reproduce this figure with Python.

here is the code

```
>>> import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> g = sns.pairplot(iris, vars = iris.columns[0:4] , diag_kind = 'hist')
```

the output (fig_2) is

[image]

How to set the color of the dots except for the main diagonal, shown as the fig_1?

I've also tried `hue` option which colors the main diagonal as well, that's why I said "except for the main diagonal".

Comment: Check `PairGrid` instead. Use `hue` only for the off-diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g = g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot, hue=iris['species'])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `sns.pairplot(iris,hue="species",diag_kws=dict(color="b"))`.

The diag_kws applies the values to only the diagonal plots